# API Google Não aparece na minha pagina

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, google, maps

Ola, estou tentando inserir o `google maps` num site `MVC` que o `Visual Studio 2012` já disponibiliza para teste. Tirando só a parte do `maps` e colocando num `aspx` avulso, ele gera o mapa bonitinho do jeito que preciso mas quando jogo ele em uma `div` dentro da pagina "contact" ou qualquer outa pagina do `MVC` ele não aparece. Alguém sabe me explicar o porque ou o que tenho que fazer para esse mapa aparecer na `div` certinha.

> <%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"" > AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Contact.aspx.vb" Inherits="Contact" %>

```
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>Telefones</h1>

</hgroup>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Contatos:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Principal:</span>
        <span>+55 (31) 3218-1500</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Horário de plantão:</span>
        <span>+55 (31) 9-9236-0601</span>
    </p>
</section>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Email:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Suporte:</span>
        <span><a href="suporte@informinas.com.br">Suporte@informinas.com.br</a></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Comercial:</span><br />
        <span><a>Aleandro - aleandro@informinas.com.br</a></span><br />
        <span><a>Robert - robert@informinas.com.br</a></span><br />
        <span><a>Christiano Cassio - christianocassio@informinas.com.br</a></span><br />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Gerentes:</span>
        <span><a>Leandro - leandro@informinas.com.br</a></span>
        <span><a>Frederico - frederico@informinas.com.br</a></span>
    </p>
</section>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Endereço</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        R. Álvares de Azevedo, 103 - Colégio Batista, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31110-290
    </p>
</section>

<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  .wrap { max-width: 75em; min-height: 40em; height:100%; width:100%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 2.5%;}
  #map-canvas { height: 40%;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-left: 200px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAxr6e8Ki1o0TdrP4YLE_DwoiZfKkI-4dQ&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.9084715, -43.9395248);
    var zoomLevel = 17;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: centerPos,
            zoom: zoomLevel
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var locations = [['Informinas', -19.9084715, -43.9395248]];


        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                title: locations[i][0],
                map: map

            });
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o elemento definido aqui como map-canvas

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
```

não está definido em nenhum lugar na sua view. Além disso, não parece que o método initialize está sendo chamado em nenhum lugar.

Se não for problema, coloque todo o conteudo do método initialize dentro de

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

porque desta forma vai ser executado sempre que a view terminar de carregar ;)

Comment: Coloquei uma <div class="wrap"> <div id="map-canvas"> e codigo dentro do $(document).ready(function(){ jQuery }); mas não funcionou :/ . tem outro lugar para colocar ou eu que não to sabendo chamar ele nessa div?

Comment: Consegui colocar fazer aperecer depois que setei em um div, foi só colocar o atributo no css "position: absolute;"